# Problems with reCatptcha and GenemenuFormBundle

Tags: symfony, recaptcha, symfony-2.3

I am trying to add a re-captcha in my forms using `GenemuFormBundle`, I followed all the steps in the documentation but I got this error when I try to load the form:

> Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPath", "boolean" given

I don't want to store the captcha in the database, thats why I am setting:

```
->add('captcha', 'genemu_recaptcha', array("property_path" => false));
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there an example for the view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `property_path` is deprecated, you should use `mapped` option:

```
->add('captcha', 'genemu_recaptcha', array("mapped" => false));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its all I needed for solve the problem, but I still need help in the view, I wrote this code:

`{{ form_widget(form) }}`

in my twig template, and all widgets showed correctly, except the recaptcha, that only showed the label. 

Am I missing any javascript file???

Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured "re-captcha"? https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/recaptcha/default.md

Comment: I am trying to configure this, but I dunno what "code" and "proxy" are, any lead? Public & private key are OK!

Comment: You may ask an other question